# Load pages using jQuery/Ajax in the same div that loads a page every 6 sec?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

On my index.php I have a header, sidebar, footer and the main part of it is the `<div id="feed">` that loads engine.php every 6000 ms.

I have a Contact page ( contact.php ) in my sidebar. Instead of copying my index.php to a new page, with header, sidebar, footer and a main div for the contact content, can I load it in the #feed div of index.php withour refreshing the site in the browser?

To summarize it, my question is, is there any way that my pages to be loaded on the same div ( #feed) without refresh and freeze the setTimeout timer?

When the user click back on Home, then the engine.php is loaded and reloaded every 6 seconds.

Maybe this can be done with Ajax, I don't know...

Thank you for this and any examples/codes are highly appreciated.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
$(function () {
    function loadfeed() {
        $('#feed')
            .addClass('loading')
            .load('engine.php', function () {
                $(this).removeClass('loading');
                setTimeout(loadfeed, 6000);
        });
    }

    loadfeed();
});
</script>
```

**Update**

Having something like this works, but the engine.php loads after 6 sec.

```
$("#contactBtn").click(function() {
  $("#feed").load('contact.php');
});
```

Comment: Are you asking if you can load the content of contact.php in the same div as the content of engine.php? If so, then no. Not without freezing the timer. Otherwise, engine.php will wipe out your contact information after 6 sec.

Comment: @Herbert Yes this is what am I asking. Is there any other way for doing this?

Comment: I provided an answer that _may_ work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no way of fully testing this, but you try something like this.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
var timerID;

$(function () {
    function loadfeed() {
        $('#feed')
            .addClass('loading')
            .load('engine.php', function () {
                $(this).removeClass('loading');
                timerID = setTimeout(loadfeed, 6000);
        });
    }

    $("#contactBtn").click(function() {
        clearTimeout(timerID);
        $("#feed").load('contact.php');
        $("#feedBtn").bind('click', loadfeed);
    });

    loadfeed();
});
</script>
```

The key here is the use of a global `timerID` variable and the `clearTimeout()` function.

If this works, you can include a *Return to feeds* button with `id="feedBtn"` in `contact.php`, but you’ll have to bind the `loadfeed` function to the button’s click event after loading it.

Comment: It worked, thank you for this, I added the timer to the link that get's me home again with engine.php

Comment: @Nikolai: Glad it worked! Adding the timer code to the link works. I suggested binding because I'm in the habit of keeping Javascript **completely** separate from HTML. It's good practice, but by no means _law_.

Comment: Yes, your solution on binding it is better than what I used.

Answer (score 1):

Without interrupting the timeout cycle, the contact form will display for a maximum of 6 seconds inside `#feed` before the next `$.load` request finishes.

If you want to leave the timeout cycle going, rather than putting everything in `#feed`, you can give it an appropriate sibling:

```
<div id="panels">
    <div id="feed">
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
    <div id="contact" style="display:none">
        <!-- ... -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, switch which is currently displaying:

```
$('a.contact').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#contact').show();
    $('#panels > div:not(#contact)').hide();
});

$('a.feed').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $('#feed').show();
    $('#panels > div:not(#feed)').hide();
});
```

The feed will continue to load into `#feed`, while the contact page can display uninterrupted.

---

Also, if you supply a clue on your links, you can combine those click handlers with fair ease:

```
<div id="menu">
    <a href="feed.php" data-panel="feed">Feed</a>
    <a href="contact.php" data-panel="contact">Contact</a>
</div>

<script>
$('#menu > a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var panel = $(this).data('panel'); // or $(this).attr('data-panel') for jQuery 1.4 or older
    $('#' + panel).show();
    $('#panels > div:not(#' + panel + ')').hide();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I checked your first example, works, but I don't want to load all the website. For the second example, I do not know how to set the div correctly. I created a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DCcG4/1/ you may have a look at it.

Comment: I wrote it with the assumption of a container element -- in this case, `#panels`. You'll also want to hide the non-default panels with `style="display:none"`. I updated the fiddle to demo: <http://jsfiddle.net/DCcG4/2/>

Answer (score 0):

You can load a file with $.load

```
$("#contactBtn").click(function() {
  $("#feed").load('contact.html') No need for a callback or the timeout.
}
```

Check the jquery docs if you're looking for something more specific.  Hope that helps.

Comment: I used your example, it changed my page but engine.php loaded after 6 sec.